# How to set primary key on an object that implements RealmModel

Tags: java, android, realm

I have an object that implements RealmModel instead of RealmObject. How do I set a primary key on this? I thought the @PrimaryKey annotation would work but I'm seeing the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A RealmObject with no @PrimaryKey cannot be updated:`

The RealmObject is not a RealmObject. It's a regular object which implements RealmModel, so the error is already confusing.

I'm also not seeing this error in my debug builds. Is there something I need to do with proguard? Your documentation states that proguard config is provided in the library already...

Comment: By adding the following proguard rules (https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-realm.pro) I was able to fix this issue. Again, shouldn't Realm already have these proguard rules?

Comment: We do. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.90.0: `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.90.0"`